# Interpreting overlapping CI for OR (basic question)

Tags: confidence-interval

I'm unsure of how to interpret the following results from an article I'm currently reading. The paper presents the odds ratio for an event and has several groups based on the presence/lack of a and b.

a-/b-: reference,
a-/b+: 2.18 (95% CI 1.12-4.24),
a+/b+: 2.41 (95% CI 1.24-4.64).

Can the overlapping CI's for a-/b+ and a+/b+ be used to conclude that there is no significant difference between them or is that incorrect?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there is relatively very little difference (compared to reference `a-/b-`) between `a-/b+` and `a+/b+`. And yes, if you would run a test to assess differences between the three groups (without inclusion of any further variables), than there certainly should be no significant difference between `a-/b+` and `a+/b+`.

Comment: Thank you for your input, appreciate it!